# Webfont won't load through CloudFront even with Access-Control-Allow-Origin set in the server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-cloudfront

I want to use cloudfront as a CDN to speed up a site. I've got all the JS & CSS working fine but I'm stuck on some webfonts which won't load from the CDN.

I've setup Apache VHOSTS file with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` using the following syntax:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*.example.com"
```

Have I put in the correct domain for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin or should it be http://www.example.com? In this case http://cdn.example.com is the CNAME point to the cloudfront DNS.

When I curl I get headings like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 41012
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 09 Jun 2013 20:59:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 May 2012 12:36:06 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.example.com
Age: 1805
Via: 1.0 cbe4bca697a4e3585803757de75edba7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 2im15Ds6Vk81kxdZKtPh7w0JUjW9qyPMgFbnXzrN_RfxJCkeyOjEbg==
```

But when I look at the same file in Firebug I don't see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

The fonts are called in a stylesheet in this manner

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'TitilliumRegular';
 src: url('TitilliumText1.eot');
 src: local('Titillium Regular'), local('Titillium-Bold'), url('TitilliumText1.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This stylesheet is then imported into another using `@import url("../fonts/titillium/stylesheet.css");`

I've read various posts on the CORS and cloudfront and as far as I can tell, the settings are correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to fix above problem required two things:

1. Converted `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the domain to *
2. Created a new CloudFront distribution as it was nearly impossible to invalidate the fonts within the cache

Once this was done, it all worked fine.

Comment: After multiple invalidation attempts, recreating the CF distribution was the only thing that worked for me as well. Weird, in another case invalidations worked fine and the new headers were picked up correctly...

Comment: Recreating the distribution sounds like a rather harsh and inconvenient fix.